# Attempting to create excel database that flags a date (90, 120, 150) from a date column and produces an input "SOMETHING IS DUE" in another column

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula

The current IF statement I am attempting is:

```
=IF(D4<=TODAY()-90,"AWARD DUE",IF(D4>=TODAY()-91 AND D4<=TODAY()-120,"INPUTS DUE",IF(D4>=TODAY()-121 AND D4<=TODAY()-150,"PREPARE INPUTS","")))
```

but excel will not run the program and states, "There's a problem with this formula."

I am having trouble figuring out what the issue is and how to fix it.  Any help in the right direction is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: `AND` is done: `AND(1stArgument,2ndArgument)` not `1stArgument AND 2ndArgument`

Comment: Thank you!  So it should be formated: =IFAND(D4>=TODAY()-91,D4<=TODAY()-120)?

Comment: close: `=IF(AND(D4>=TODAY()-91,D4<=TODAY()-120)` you forgot the `(` between the IF and the AND.

Comment: Thank you!  
=IF(D4<=TODAY()-90,"AWARD DUE",IF(AND(D4>=TODAY()-91,D4<=TODAY()-120,"INPUTS DUE",IF(AND(D4>=TODAY()-121,D4<=TODAY()-150,"PREPARE INPUTS","")))
Sorry to keep bothering you, but I am still getting the original error....